# gradle ant exclude multiple files

Tags: gradle, ant, cobertura

I have a gradle task that uses ant to create code coverage reports via Cobertura. This works as expected when excluding one file:

```
fileset(dir: classes,
    includes:"**/*.class",
    excludes:"**/*Test.class")
```

But when I want to exclude multiple files the `*Test.class` files remain exlcuded but not the `*Jar.class`.

```
fileset(dir: classes,
    includes:"**/*.class",
    excludes:["**/*Test.class", "**/*Jar.java"])
```

I'm now testing this with one file but the end goal is to exclude an entire package. What would be the correct syntax for excluding multiple files?

Entire gradle task:

```
logger.info "Configuring Cobertura Plugin"

configurations{
  coberturaRuntime {extendsFrom testRuntime}
}

dependencies {
  coberturaRuntime 'net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:2.1.1'
}

def serFile="${project.buildDir}/cobertura.ser"
def classes="${project.buildDir}/"
def classesCopy="${classes}-copy"


task cobertura(type: Test){
  dependencies {
    testRuntime 'net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:2.1.1'
  }

  systemProperty "net.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile", serFile
}

cobertura.doFirst  {
  logger.quiet "Instrumenting classes for Cobertura"
  ant {
    delete(file:serFile, failonerror:false)
    delete(dir: classesCopy, failonerror:false)
    copy(todir: classesCopy) { fileset(dir: classes) }

    taskdef(resource:'tasks.properties', classpath: configurations.coberturaRuntime.asPath)
    'cobertura-instrument'(datafile: serFile) {
      fileset(dir: classes,
              includes:"**/*.class",
              excludes:["**/*Test.class", "**/*Jar.class"])
    }
  }
}

cobertura.doLast{
  if (new File(classesCopy).exists()) {
    //create html cobertura report
    // ant.'cobertura-report'(destdir:"${project.reportsDir}/cobertura",
    //         format:'html', srcdir:"src/main/java", datafile: serFile)
    //create xml cobertura report
     ant.'cobertura-report'(destdir:"${project.reportsDir}/cobertura",
            format:'xml', srcdir:"src/main/java", datafile: serFile)
    ant.delete(file: classes)
    ant.move(file: classesCopy, tofile: classes)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be quite simple. Instead of giving the includes and excludes as parameters to fileset it is possible to use multiple include and exclude methods inside a fileset method. So replace the fileset line from my question with this:

```
fileset(dir: classes) {
    include(name: "**/*.class")
    exclude(name: "**/*Test.class")
    exclude(name: "**/*Jar.class")
}
```

I found this in gradles documentation about passing nested elements to an Ant task.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html#example_passing_nested_elements_to_an_ant_task